# Constrained optimisation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints

I have some function `f(x)`, where `x` is a six-element vector. I want to find a minimum of this function using

`x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,B)`

I have the following constraints:

`a*x1<b*x2<c*x3` and `d*x4<e*x5`, where `a,b,c,d,e` are some numbers.

My problem is to write `A` and `B` parameters of `fmincon` function correctly.

Could you help me?

## Update

My problem is that I don't understand how to join inequalities:
if I want to use only `ax1<bx2` then `A=[a,-b,0,0,0]; B=0`, if I want to use `bx2<cx3`, then `A=[0,b,-c,0,0]; B=0`. But I could not join these constraints.

May I use `A=[[a,-b,0,0,0],[0;b;-c;0;0]]; B = [0,0];`?

Comment: what have you tried and why does it not work?

Comment: Have you tried what you ask? have you read the documentation (where it is explained)? What did you not understand from the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the constraint matrix `A` and vector `B` like below

```
A = [a,-b,0,0,0;
     0,b,-c,0,0;
     0,0,0,d,-e];

B = zeros(3,1);
```